# Angular js doesn't support in IE8

Tags: angularjs

Angular js 1.15 doesn't support in IE8....How to Fix this problem?

**My coding**

I already added ie8 shim..it's not supported

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.7/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.7/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.2/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.2/es6-sham.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/es7-shim@latest"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzhaZ.png)

[IE browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf1sk.png)

Comment: Microsoft don't support ie8 anymore... drop support

Comment: @Balakumaran there is no solution to your problem.

Comment: What is the error?